# Finding the total number of non-NAN elements in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I know the df.count() and df.groupby.count(), but I simply want the number of non-NAN elements for a specific column (say called 'cars') of my dataframe.

I know df.size[0], but this command does not respect the fact that the number of non-NAN elements might differ in different columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also Series `count`. It also ignores `NaN`. From the docs

```
s = pd.Series([0.0, 1.0, np.nan])
s.count()

Out[307]: 2
```

So, for column `cars`

```
df['cars'].count()
```

will return number of Non-NaN values of column `cars`

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [`Series.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) + [`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html)

```
df.cars.notna().sum()
```